# k9copy & acidrip do not see DVD but VLC plays it just fine

Tags: 12.04, dvd

Bought "Up in the Air".  Like to make backup copies to take w/ me when I travel.  VLC plays the dvd perfectly.  I run either k9copy or acidrip and neither one 'sees' the movie in sr0.  I've had this happen w/ a couple of other dvds recently.  Is there a new encryption out?

I've tried this on my XP box using DVDShrink and the program not only crashes, the computer reboots!

What's going on?

Now have tried dvd::rip.  The program crashes!  Dvd95 converter crashes!

HELP!